# Build function returns null in Flutter form validation

Tags: forms, flutter

I'm building a form with validation with Flutter and I face a problem. I'm quite surprised as I'm - for now - following official documentation. I have looked at many websites and my code looks similar, but I still get an error.

My code:

```
class addObjectForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  addObjectFormState createState() => addObjectFormState();
}

class addObjectFormState extends State<addObjectForm> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      MyObject _insertedObject = MyObject();

      return Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Insert object name"),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please insert a value';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onSaved: (value) => _insertedObject.objectName = value,
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Add"),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    _formKey.currentState.save();
                    //To be changed to change state and save it into the global object list
                    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        SnackBar(content: Text('Object has been added')));
                  }
                },
              )
            ],
          ));
    }
  }
} //End of addObjectFormState
```

The error message (in the iOS simulator, not in VSCode):

[image: Error message]

Thank you !

Comment: Regarding your code, the build method will return a Form widget !
Maybe your problem is elsewhere ? Do VsCode give you the line number where the error occurs ?

Comment: I get the error when I navigate on the page with the form. I don't even see the form. VSCode doesn't return any error. I can "compile". App works well until I want to access the form.

Comment: Your code may compile without any error but may crash at runtime. You can check the debug console from vscode to check your error

Comment: Indeed ! VSCode gives a line number corresponding to the line where I define my routes in MaterialApp. This route refers to widget "addObjectForm".

Comment: So I Guess your problem is rather there. Can you share your code of MaterialApp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the build function inside another build function:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) { // Build method 1
    final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) { // Build method 2 (placed inside first)
      MyObject _insertedObject = MyObject();
```

So basically you have implemented everything inside the second build method. And you are not returning anything from the first one, that's the reason for the error.